# How can I repeat the two defined functions 5 times? Python

Tags: python, loops

I need to have both defined programs repeat 5 times
Here is my success criteria:
The program will allow each player to roll two 6-sided dice
The program will calculate and output the points each round for a players total score
The program will allow the players to play 5 rounds
The program will allow each player to roll 1 die each until someone wins if both players have the same score after 5 rounds
The program will output who has won at the of the 5 rounds
The program will let the player roll an extra die and get the number of points rolled added to their score if they roll a double
The program will not allow the score to go below 0 at any point

```
import random

def player_one():

  global score1
  print("Player One is up first")
  roll = str(input("Please enter ROLL to roll the dice >")).upper()
  num1 = random.randint(1,6)
  num2 = random.randint(1,6)
  if roll == "ROLL":
    showscore1 = print("You rolled a",num1,"and a",num2)
  else:
    exit()
  score1 = num1 + num2
  if (score1 % 2) == 0:  
    score1 = score1 + 10
  else:
    score1 = score1 - 5
  if score1 < 0:
    score1 = 0
  else:
    score1 = score1
  print("Your score was",score1)
  return score1
player_one()

import time
time.sleep(3)

def player_two():
  global score2
  print("Player Two is up first")
  roll = str(input("Please enter ROLL to roll the dice >")).upper()
  num1 = random.randint(1,6)
  num2 = random.randint(1,6)
  if roll == "ROLL":
    showscore1 = print("You rolled a",num1,"and a",num2)
  else:
    exit()
  score2 = num1 + num2
  if (score2 % 2) == 0:  
    score2 = score2 + 10
  else:
    score2 = score2 - 5
  if score2 < 0:
    score2 = 0
  else:
    score2 = score2
  print("Your score was",score2)
  return score2
player_two()

time.sleep(2)

if score1 > score2:
  print("Player One has won the game!")
else:
  print("Player Two has won the game!")
```

Not needed but if you could add some more of my success criteria to my program would be helpful, but for now I'm really looking for the loop. Thanks

The additional success criteria would be:
The program will allow each player to roll 1 die each until someone wins if both players have the same score after 5 rounds
The program will output who has won at the of the 5 rounds
The program will let the player roll an extra die and get the number of points rolled added to their score if they roll a double

Comment: Sounds a bit like a homework question, but I'll play along. I would first look at using a `while` loop and incrementing a counter variable for each player each time their function is executed (i.e. they roll the die)

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
for x in range(0,5):
    function()
```

the function will be run 5 times. Also, using `global` is bad practice. You should return the values from the function and assign them to variables. I recently did this same challenge, and this is my solution: https://pastebin.com/Zc1nj0Mi